# Alljoyn - 15.09a build - linking issue on pi

Tags: build, raspberry-pi, alljoyn

15.09 does build fine on my normal linux system (ubuntu 64bit 14.04).
When trying to build Alljoyn 15.09a on my raspberry pi b+ 
using

scons CPU=arm OE_BASE=/usr CROSS_COMPILE=/usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- BINDINGS=cpp BT=off ICE=off WS=off

the build stops with with a linker error when linking alljoyn/test/proptester

anyone else encountering this?

15.04 builds fine on the pi.
15.09 fails the same way.

Is there a way to disable building the test programs?

Only thing I saw inside the bug tracker that might be related is:
https://jira.allseenalliance.org/browse/ASACORE-2642

Comment: What's the linker error?

Comment: ends with: Install file: "build/linux/arm/debug/obj/alljoyn_core/test/propstresstest" as "build/linux/arm/debug/dist/cpp/bin/propstresstest"
        [CXX]     alljoyn_core/test/proptester.cc
        [LINK]    build/linux/arm/debug/obj/alljoyn_core/test/proptester
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
scons: *** [build/linux/arm/debug/obj/alljoyn_core/test/proptester] Error 1
not much information,...